# Model using tensorflow probability always predicts the sample mean

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to set up a model using Tensorflow and Tensorflow Probability. The model I'm trying to learn concerns a dataset of a bunch of survey respondents, each of whom are described a bunch of features and also a score. I'm trying to predict scores based on features. However, for each individual, I want to be able to predict both a mean and a standard deviation - hence the TFP.

Right now, I have a model that looks like this:

```
nn_model = tfk.Sequential([
 norm_layer,
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
```

where `norm_layer` is an instance of `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()`.

When I fit the model, I use the following loss:

```
def negloglik(y_true, y_pred):
 dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=y_pred[:, 0], scale=tf.math.softplus(y_pred[:, 1]))
 return -tf.reduce_mean(dist.log_prob(y_true))
```

However, when I go to make predictions with my network, it predicts (pretty much) the same thing for everybody in the testing set -- the mean of the scores in the training set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! Would you mind sharing a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example? This would allow me to run your code and see what's going on. Thanks!